# knockout function with multiple if

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm using knockout, I have an array of contacts, which contains an array of organizations objects.

organizations object properties :
example 1
firm: "Zensql" 
kind: "work"
newOrUpdatedField: true
title: null
updatedField: false

example 2 full informations
firm: "SAGI"
kind: "work"
newOrUpdatedField: false
title: "Community Manager"
updatedField: false

```
<div id="retrievedContactsDiv" data-bind="foreach: viewModel.MoreContacts.contacts()">

          <!-- ko foreach: $data.organizations() -->

            <!-- ko ifnot: ($data.title == null) && ($data.firm == '')-->
          <span  data-bind="text: $data.title()"></span> at
          <span data-bind="text: $data.firm()"></span> <br> 
           <!-- /ko -->

            <!-- ko if:$data.title == null -->
          <span data-bind="text: $data.firm()"></span>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if:$data.firm == "" -->
             <span data-bind="text: $data.title()"></span>
             <!-- /ko -->

          <!-- /ko -->
```

I would like display " title at firm " only when I have full infos, if title == null
firm only and if firm == "" title only.... I tried this code but not working...

Comment: It would be helpful if you didn't remove your code so that others can learn from the problems you had.

Comment: Or it would be really nice if you just deleted the question instead.

Answer (score 1):

You have to unwrap observables (Add `()`) when use it in expression. Update your code as follow:

```
      <!-- ko foreach: $data.organizations() -->

      <!-- ko ifnot: ($data.title() == null) && ($data.firm() == '')-->
      <span  data-bind="text: $data.title()"></span> at
      <span data-bind="text: $data.firm()"></span> <br> 
      <!-- /ko -->

      <!-- ko if:$data.title() == null -->
      <span data-bind="text: $data.firm()"></span>
      <!-- /ko -->
      <!-- ko if:$data.firm() == "" -->
      <span data-bind="text: $data.title()"></span>
      <!-- /ko -->

      <!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: thx for help, I still have a problem, cause I have an " at Zensql  " whereas it should be only "Zensql" displayed